# How to find focus and directrix of $4y = x^2 -16$

Tags: analytic-geometry, recreational-mathematics, conic-sections

How would I go about finding the focus and directrix of $4y = x^2 -16$ $(1)$

I did the $SP^2 = QP^2$ and got $(y+b)^2 = (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2$.

This gave me: $4by = x^2 -2ax +a^2$. Comparing this to $(1)$. I get $a = 0$ but I don't know what to do to get $b$. Can someone advise?

Edit: my workings:
[image]

Comment: The equation is equivalently $x^2=4(y+4)$. This is a translated version (vertex is $(0,-4)$) of a vertical parabola of general equation, when the vertex is the origin, given by: $x^2=4py$, where $p$ represents the distance from the origin to the focus and from the origin to the directrix. Compare it with the general form.

Comment: @user7857462 Is there an algebraic way to arrive at this solution. I noticed the inspection way comparing it to the standard base result but wasn't happy with this approach so am looking for an algebraic way that forces a solution without too much thinking.

Comment: I would suggest that after you know that the parabola is vertical you would know that the focus would have the same abcissa of the vertex and the directrix is horizontal. So you're looking for a point $F(0,p)$ and a line $(d):y-4=p$ where $p$ is undertermined. The reason why I said all of this is the definition of a parabola of focus F and directrix (d) "the set of points whose distance from the focus equals the distance from the directrix". By choosing a point on the parabola you can determine p solving it algebraically(other than the vertex which gave us the form of F and (d)).

Comment: Hi again, I added a picture of my workings in my initial post. I found the focus and directrix assuming the parabola was not shifted, then compared this to the actual parabola and defined the new focus and directrix accordingly, i.e. y=-b-4, and F(0,b-4). Then I subbed b=1 from the unshifted parabola ie 4y=x^2. Would this way work? Not fully algebraic but possibly the most elegant/simplest solution. Thanks. Edit: looks like your p=y-4 way is identical to my picture? Think I got confused with the y.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(P): 4y=x^2-16$ be the parabola of focus $F$ and directrix $(d)$. By definition, the distance from any point $M$ on $(P)$ to the directrix $(d)$ equals the distance from $M$ to the focus $F$. Moreover, since $(P)$ is vertical and directed upwards, the focus is above the vertex and the directrix is horizontal and below it. We will use this in two steps.

1- Note that $(P)$ has a vertex $V(0,-4)$. This means that $F$ has a zero abcissa, say $(d):y=a$ and $F(0,b)$. Since $(d)$ is below the vertex and $F$ is above it, $a<-4$ and $b>-4$.
As the vertex $V$ is a point on $(P)$, then:

> $VF=distance(V$$\rightarrow$$(d))$. Meaning $|-4-b|=|-4-a|$. Which gives $b+4=-4-a$. This implies that $a=-b-8$.

> This enables us to write $F(0,b)$ and $(d):y=-b-8$ where $b$ is to be determined.

2- Choose another point on $(P)$, say $M(4,0)$. Then:

> $MF^2=distance(M$$\rightarrow$$(d))^2$. Meaning $(4-0)^2+(0-b)^2=(-b-8)^2$, which gives $b=-3$. This gives $a=-5$.

Hence the focus is $F(0,-3)$ and the directrix is$(d):y=-5$.

Comment: Works but it’s a bit long winded. Guess inspection is the best solution. I did: x^2 =4(y+4), then I compared this to x^2 =4by (standard form), and I asked, what do I need to do to the expression to match the forms. I concluded b=1, and the +4 needs a -4 to cancel the 4 out and make it a y. So then I did b=1-4=-3. Ie focus =(0,-3). Something about this method feels wishy-washy. Is this a valid way of working and will it always work?

Comment: You can prove that if the focus and directrix of a vertical parabola directed upwards are given, then the general form would look like this. You just take an arbitrary point (x,y) on the parabola and use the definition of a parabola to determine the general equation. After all this, it would be reasonable to compare the equation given with the general form and then determine the focus and directrix. It will always work for a vertical parabola directed upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use definition of parabola as stated in comment:

$\sqrt{[(y-b)-a]^2+x^2}=(y-b)+a$

$(y-b)^2-2a(y-b)+a^2+x^2=(y-b)^2+2a(y-b)+a^2$

Which gives:

$4a(y-b)=x^2$

Comparing with given equation $x^2=4y+16$ we get:

$b=-4$ and $a=1$, where b is value of translation in y direction. The coordinates of vertex is (0, -4), therefore:

Equation of directrix is L: $y=-1-4=-5$.

Coordinate of focus is: $F(0, -3)$.

Comment: Why did you do y-b -a? The -a bit confuses me

Comment: @Noobcoder, For example if the center of a circle is on origin then it's equation is $(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2=x^2+y^2=r^2$. If center of the circle is translated at distance b in y direction then it's equation is:$(x-0)^2+(y-b)^2=x^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$.

Comment: Hi again, I follow the y-b but the -a is still confusing as by inspection isn’t a=0? I defined my original focus as: S(a,b), where a= 0 as the parabola is symmetric about the y-axis. What is ‘a’ defined as in your solution? Thanks

Comment: @Noobcoder, due to definition a is distance between focus and vertex =distance between vertex and directrix, so it can not be zero.